# Making all textboxes on form1 and inside groupboxs invisible

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to make selected textboxes on form1 and textboxes inside groupboxs1 invisible

I have 8 textboxes, 1 to 4 on form1 and textboxes 5 to 8 in  groupbox1 also on form1

I want textboxes 3, 4, 5 and 6 to be invisible by clicking a button
the following code only make textboxes 3 and 4 invisible leaving textboxes 5 and 6 visible

```
For i = 3 To 6
  Dim c As String = "ComboBox" & i.ToString
  DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find(c, False)(0), ComboBox).Visible = False
Next
```

I found this code that works but will only make "ALL" the textboxes inside the groupbox1 invisible but not the textboxes on form1

```
Dim Ctl As Control
For Each Ctl In Controls
  If TypeOf Ctl Is GroupBox Then
    Dim Ctl1 As Control
    For Each Ctl1 In Ctl.Controls
      If TypeOf Ctl1 Is TextBox Then
        Ctl1.Visible = True
      End If
    Next
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Don't try to be fancy. If you wanted all controls of a type to be treated the same way then a generic loop like that would be fine. If you want specific controls to be treated one way and others to be treated another, just specify those controls. The code you have is longer than what would be required to simply set the `Visible` property or call `Show` or `Hide` on the relevant controls. If you had a large number of controls then maybe you'd have a point, but for four controls, just specify those four controls.

Comment: BTW, you say `TextBoxes` in the title and the question but the first code snippet refers to `ComboBoxes`. If that's your problem then you need to facepalm. Regardless, there's no point casting any type of control as any other type to set the `Visible` property because it is a member of the `Control` class.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's jmcilhinney I know i put 1 to 8 textboxes but i'm working with over 130 textboxes and I use this code that works great.

```
 For i = 3 To 6
        Dim c As String = "textBox" & i.ToString
        DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find(c, False)(0), textBox).Visible = False
    Next
```

(Yes I did have combobox in they first message I copied the wrong code)
How ever the code above will not do any textboxes

Now I have it working with the following code if it help's anyone

```
  For i = 46 To 78
        Dim c As String = "textbox" & i.ToString
        DirectCast(GroupBox1.Controls.Find(c, False)(0), TextBox).Visible = False
    Next
```

Comment: If I had to work with a form with controls named `textbox1` to `textbox130`, I'd delete the Form and code and start over.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)